# Objective-C & NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just started developing iOS using objective-c, and I've had some trouble getting used to the syntax. i made a signup form in objective c how i can stored fields information in NSDictionary

Comment: You should add some code in your post. It would be easier to help you

Comment: Refer this : http://hayageek.com/nsdictionary-nsmutabledictionary/

Comment: Refer : http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary

Comment: can you show your tried code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// You have already all objects

```
NSString *loginString = @"user1";
NSString *passwordString = @"password1";
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"login":loginString, @"password":passwordString};
```

// You do not have all objects

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

//When you have loginString you add it to the mDict

[mDict setObject:@"user2" forKey:@"login"];

//When you have passwordString you add it to the mDict

[mDict setObject:@"password2" forKey:@"password"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"firstname"       : txtAddFirstName.text,
                     @"lastname"        :txtAddLastName.text,
                     @"region"          :txtRegion.text,
                     @"street"          :txtVAddress.text,
                     @"company"         :txtAddCompny.text,
                     @"city"            :txtCity.text,
                     @"country"         : countryCode,
                     @"postcode"        :txtZip.text,
                     @"telephone"       :txtTelephone.text,
                     @"fax"             :txtFax.text,
                    };
```